# Compare statistical significance between 3 main groups and subgroups

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, p-value, modeling, multiple-comparisons

I am working on a research paper that is comparing the draft values between 3 main categorical players in baseball - infielders, outfielders, and pitchers, and 2 subcategories - being drafted out of college and high school. Sparing all details, the ind.. variables are WAR (wins above replacement) that compares all 3 categories, OPS (on base plus slugging) that compares infielders and outfielders, batting average that compares infielders and outfielders, and innings pitched that compares hs vs. college drafted college players.

Are there any statistical recommendations that you would give to try? So far I have done the means, sd's, and ANOVA for individual categories, but I lack cross categorical statistic test to compare the two. I hope to be able to obtain p, B, and possibly t but is struggling to include that in the data too as a whole.